# How to understand the same <test> tag in test ng?

Tags: java, testng

"parallel="tests": TestNG will run all the methods **in the same  tag** in the same thread, but each  tag will be in a separate thread. This allows you to group all your classes that are not thread safe in the same  and guarantee they will all run in the same thread while taking advantage of TestNG using as many threads as possible to run your tests."

How to understand the same test tag in testNG?

Comment: *"can you help to give examples"*  Can you pay us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example taken from testng site
In below : NoPackage and Regression1 are two separate test tags.
If you run parallel = tests then NoPackageTest and ParameterSample class would run in different threads, but ParameterSample and ParameterTest would run in the same thread.
Hope it clarifies..

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Nopackage" >
    <classes>
       <class name="NoPackageTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Regression1">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample"/>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```